# Lexical analyzer, Compare two different lines of a text file

Tags: visual-c++, lexical-analysis

I have to use a lexical analyzer to compare 2 lines of a text file, if the 2 lines are identical  I merge them this way:

```
STATE a TO a b b b OUT 0 1 1 0 
STATE b TO a b b b OUT 0 1 1 0
```

```
STATE ab TO a b b b OUT 0 1 1 0
```

Current_State = a 
Next_States = a b b b 
Outputs = 0 1 1 0 
I've ignored in the text file everything that comes before the state, 
my code is as follows :

```
#pragma warning(disable:4786)

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
#define Getc(s) getc(s)
#define Ungetc(c) {ungetc(c,IP_Input); ugetflag=1;}

typedef vector<string> list; // Um Eingänge ausgänge zu speichern 
list next_states;
list Outputs;
int tok = 0;

/*
* Lexical analyzer states.
*/
enum parcases {     // Case that can occur C_..... 
 c_SkipBegin,        // When State is found go to DEFCURRENTSTATE
 c_DEFCURRENTSTATE,  // DEFCURRENTSTATE occurs scan the states
 c_DEFNEXTSTATES,    // DEFNEXTSTATES occurs scan the next states
 c_DEFOUT,           //DEFOUT occurs scan the outputs
 c_FINISHED
};

enum lexstate {
 L_START, L_INT, L_IDENT, L_STRING, L_STRING2,
 L_COMMENT, L_TEXT_COMMENT, L_LINE_COMMENT, L_END_TEXT_COMMENT
};
const int STRING1 = 3;
const int IDENTIFIER = 4;
const int INTEGER1 = 5;
const int TOKENSTART = 300;
class CParser
{
public:

 string yytext; //input buffer
 struct tyylval { //value return structure
     string s; //string
     int i; //integer
 }yylval;
 FILE* IP_Input; //Input File
 FILE* IP_Error; //Error Output
 FILE* IP_List; //List Output
 int IP_LineNumber; //Line counter
 int ugetflag; //checks ungets
 int prflag; //controls printing
 map<string, int> IP_Token_table; //Tokendefinitions
 map<int, string> IP_revToken_table; //reverse Tokendefinitions

 string current_states;   // Vector um scanned_states zu speichern
 list first_lines;
 list next_states;   // Vector um scanned_inputs zu speichern
 list Outputs;   // Vector um scanned_outputs zu speichern


 int yylex(); //lexical analyser
 void yyerror(char* ers); //error reporter
 int IP_MatchToken(string& tok); //checks the token
 void InitParse(FILE* inp, FILE* err, FILE* lst); //Sets the File pointers
 int yyparse(); //parser
 list fusion_lines(list& list_one, list& list_two);
 bool compare(list& list_one, list& list_two);
 void pr_tokentable(); //test output for tokens
 void IP_init_token_table(); //loads the tokens
 void Load_tokenentry(string str, int index); //load one token
 void PushString(char c); //Used for dtring assembly

 parcases SkipTillBegin(int tok, list& first_lines);// Skip till begin is found
 parcases ScanTheCurrentState(int tok, string& current_states); // Scan the STATE 
 parcases ScanTheNextStates(int tok, list& next_states); // Scan the TO STATE
 parcases ScanTheOutputs(int tok, list& Outputs);    // Scan the Outputs

 CParser() { IP_LineNumber = 1; ugetflag = 0; prflag = 0; }; //Constructor
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Adds a character to the string value
void CParser::PushString(char c)
{
 yylval.s += c;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CParser::Load_tokenentry(string str, int index)
{
 IP_Token_table[str] = index;
 IP_revToken_table[index] = str;
}
void CParser::IP_init_token_table()
{
 Load_tokenentry("STRING1", 3);
 Load_tokenentry("IDENTIFIER", 4);
 Load_tokenentry("INTEGER1", 5);
 int ii = TOKENSTART;
 Load_tokenentry("AND", ii++);
 Load_tokenentry("OR", ii++);
 Load_tokenentry("Begin", ii++);
 Load_tokenentry("End", ii++);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CParser::pr_tokentable()
{
 typedef map<string, int>::const_iterator CI;
 const char* buf;
 printf("Symbol Table ---------------------------------------------\n");
 for (CI p = IP_Token_table.begin(); p != IP_Token_table.end(); ++p) {
     buf = p->first.c_str();
     printf(" key:%s val:%d\n ", buf, p->second);
 }
}

int CParser::yyparse()
{

 string Current_state;

 list given_first_lines;
 list given_Next_states;
 list given_outputs;

 // Define the first state first we read the file till begin Occur what is befor "State" is ignored.
 parcases Case = c_SkipBegin;

 printf(" %s ", first_lines, "/ln");

 while ((tok = yylex()) != IP_Token_table["End"])
 {
     if (Case == c_SkipBegin)
     {
         Case = SkipTillBegin(tok, first_lines);
     }
     else if (Case == c_DEFCURRENTSTATE)
     {

     }

 }
 return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
parcases CParser::SkipTillBegin(int tok, list& first_lines)
{
 parcases retval;
 if (tok != IP_Token_table["STATE"])
 {
     first_lines.push_back(string(yylval.s));  // the 2 IN lines
     retval = c_SkipBegin;
 }
 else {
     retval = c_DEFCURRENTSTATE;
 }
 return retval;
}

parcases CParser::ScanTheCurrentState(int tok, string& current_state)
{
 parcases retval = c_DEFCURRENTSTATE;

 if (tok == IDENTIFIER)  //IDENTIFIER = a
 {
     current_state = string(yylval.s); // a,b,c

     retval = c_DEFCURRENTSTATE;
 }
 else if (tok == 'TO') {  // State is done
     retval = c_DEFNEXTSTATES;
 }

 return retval;
}

parcases CParser::ScanTheNextStates(int tok, list& next_states)
{
 parcases retval = c_DEFNEXTSTATES;

 if (tok == IDENTIFIER)  //IDENTIFIER = a
 {
     next_states.push_back(string(yylval.s));  //a, b,x
     retval = c_DEFNEXTSTATES;
 }
 else if (tok == 'OUT') {  // States are done
     retval = c_DEFOUT;
 }
 return retval;

}

parcases CParser::ScanTheOutputs(int tok, list& Outputs)
{
 parcases retval = c_DEFOUT;

 if ((tok == INTEGER1) || (tok == IDENTIFIER))  //IDENTIFIER = 1,0,x
 {
     Outputs.push_back(string(yylval.s));  //1,0,x
     retval = c_DEFOUT;
 }
 else if (tok == '\n') {  // Outputs are done
     retval = c_FINISHED;
 }
 return retval;
}

bool CParser::compare(list& list_one, list& list_two)
{
 bool match = false;

 if (list_one == list_two)
 {
     match = true;
     //list_two = 0;
 }

 return match;

}

list CParser::fusion_lines(list& list_one, list& list_two)
{

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
* Parse File:
*
*/
void CParser::InitParse(FILE* inp, FILE* err, FILE* lst)
{
 /*
 * Set up the file state to something useful.
 */
 IP_Input = inp;
 IP_Error = err;
 IP_List = lst;
 IP_LineNumber = 1;
 ugetflag = 0;
 /*
 * Define both the enabled token and keyword strings.
 */
 IP_init_token_table();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int CParser::IP_MatchToken(string& tok)
{
 int retval;
 if (IP_Token_table.find(tok) != IP_Token_table.end()) {
     retval = (IP_Token_table[tok]);
 }
 else {
     retval = (0);
 }
 return retval;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
* yylex:
*
*/
int CParser::yylex()
{
 //Locals
 int c;
 lexstate s;
 /*
 * Keep on sucking up characters until we find something which
 * explicitly forces us out of this function.
 */
 for (s = L_START, yytext = ""; 1;) {
     c = Getc(IP_Input);
     yytext = yytext + (char)c;
     if (!ugetflag) {
         if (c != EOF)if (prflag)fprintf(IP_List, "%c", c);
     }
     else ugetflag = 0;
     switch (s) {
         //Starting state, look for something resembling a token.
     case L_START:
         if (isdigit(c)) {
             s = L_INT;
         }
         else if (isalpha(c) || c == '\\') {
             s = L_IDENT;
         }
         else if (isspace(c)) {
             if (c == '\n') {
                 IP_LineNumber += 1;
                 if (prflag)
                     fprintf(IP_List, "%5d ", (int)IP_LineNumber);
             }
             yytext = "";
         }
         else if (c == '/') {
             yytext = "";
             s = L_COMMENT;
         }
         else if (c == '"') {
             s = L_STRING;
         }
         else if (c == EOF) {
             return ('\0');
         }
         else {
             return (c);
         }
         break;
     case L_COMMENT:
         if (c == '/')
             s = L_LINE_COMMENT;
         else if (c == '*')
             s = L_TEXT_COMMENT;
         else {
             Ungetc(c);
             return('/'); /* its the division operator not a comment */
         }
         break;
     case L_LINE_COMMENT:
         if (c == '\n') {
             s = L_START;
             Ungetc(c);
         }
         yytext = "";
         break;
     case L_TEXT_COMMENT:
         if (c == '\n') {
             IP_LineNumber += 1;
         }
         else if (c == '*')
             s = L_END_TEXT_COMMENT;
         yytext = "";
         break;
     case L_END_TEXT_COMMENT:
         if (c == '/') {
             s = L_START;
         }
         else {
             s = L_TEXT_COMMENT;
         }
         yytext = "";
         break;
         /*
         * Suck up the integer digits.
         */
     case L_INT:
         if (isdigit(c)) {
             break;
         }
         else {
             Ungetc(c);
             yylval.s = yytext.substr(0, yytext.size() - 1);
             yylval.i = atoi(yylval.s.c_str());
             return (INTEGER1);
         }
         break;
         /*
* Grab an identifier, see if the current context enables
* it with a specific token value.
*/

     case L_IDENT:
         if (isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || c == '_')
             break;
         Ungetc(c);
         yytext = yytext.substr(0, yytext.size() - 1);
         yylval.s = yytext;
         if (c = IP_MatchToken(yytext)) {
             return (c);
         }
         else {
             return (IDENTIFIER);
         }
         /*
         * Suck up string characters but once resolved they should
         * be deposited in the string bucket because they can be
         * arbitrarily long.
         */
     case L_STRING2:
         s = L_STRING;
         if (c == '"') {
             PushString((char)c);
         }
         else {
             if (c == '\\') {
                 PushString((char)c);
             }
             else {
                 PushString((char)'\\');
                 PushString((char)c);
             }
         }
         break;
     case L_STRING:
         if (c == '\n')
             IP_LineNumber += 1;
         else if (c == '\r')
             ;
         else if (c == '"' || c == EOF) {
             return (STRING1);
         }
         else if (c == '\\') {
             s = L_STRING2;
         }
         else
             PushString((char)c);
         break;
     default: printf("***Fatal Error*** Wrong case label in yylex\n");
     }
 }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 FILE* inf;
 CParser obj;
 //char fistr[100];
 string fistr;
 printf("Enter filename:\n");
 //gets(fistr);
 cin >> fistr;
 inf = fopen(fistr.c_str(), "r");
 if (inf == NULL) {
     printf("Cannot open input file %s\n", fistr);
     return 0;
 }
 CParser obj;
 obj.InitParse(inf, stderr, stdout);
 // obj.pr_tokentable();
 obj.yyparse();

 return 0;
 //system("pause");
}
```

I wrote this classes to put the current state, the next states and the output in a vector

`parcases CParser::SkipTillBegin(int tok, list& first_lines)` 
`parcases CParser::ScanTheCurrentState(int tok, string& current_state)` 
`parcases CParser::ScanTheNextStates(int tok, list& next_states)` 
`parcases CParser::ScanTheOutputs(int tok, list& Outputs)`

this class is the lexical analyzer it differentiates the integers of identifiers and strings

`int CParser::yylex()`

The other classes aren't really important to understand. 
I wrote this class to compare

```
bool CParser::compare(list& list_one, list& list_two)
{
 bool match = false;

 if (list_one == list_two)
 {
     match = true;
     //list_two = 0;
 }

 return match;

}
```

and I started this one to merge two lines together 
`list CParser::fusion_lines(list& list_one, list& list_two)` but i am stuck here and on the output class `int CParser::yyparse()` 


I couldn't find a way to do it correctly and to compare two different lines of the text file with the lexical analyzer.